# Does the completeness of ℝ depend on the norm we use?

Tags: real-analysis

Baby Rudin 3.11 c says in $\mathbb{R}^k$ every Cauchy sequence converges. 
Does that only works for $l$-2 norm or any kind of norm(such as Manhattan or Maximum norm)?

Comment: All norms in $\Bbb R^k$ are  topologically equivalent, so the statement holds for every norm in those spaces.

Comment: If you change the metric you can make it no longer complete, but apparently not if it's given by a norm.

Comment: @ajotatxe Tological equivalence need not preserve completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! Because all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent. That is, given 2 norms $||\cdot||_a$ and $||\cdot ||_b$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \ c||x||_a \leq ||x||_b \leq c^{-1}||x||_a $$
Therefore if $$||x_n - x^*||_b  \rightarrow 0 $$ then 
$$||x_n - x^*||_a \leq c^{-1}||x_n - x^*||_b \rightarrow 0$$
Thus if you can show every Cauchy sequence converges in one norm say $||\cdot||_b$, it must converge in all norms.

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard fact in Banach space theory that all norms in a finite dimensional vector space are indeed equivalent: For any such norms $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{2}$, there is a constant $c>0$ such that $c^{-1}\|\cdot\|_{2}\leq\|\cdot\|_{1}\leq c\|\cdot\|_{2}$, so if it were complete for one norm, the other follows.